# VB Web query request

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to send a query request from VB Login form to Website to check if user Email and Password are Valid.

If I am using request string: http://mathsquest.com/api.php?email=testemail&password=testpass
it returns value "1" as "testemail & "testpass" are pre-registered correct values.

How to send the request with user input values stored in Login form variables (EmailInput and PasswordInput)?

Thank you for help

Comment: are you sending login/pw in plain text ?

Comment: You really ought to be using HTTPS, and you should *REALLY* hash the password, at the least.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question you should build your url request and then make a redirect or an http request:

```
Dim req_url as string = "http://mathsquest.com/api.php"

req_url &= "?email=" & EmailInput & "&password=" & PasswordInput

Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient

Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString(req_url)
```

*P.S. As suggested in the comments you should consider hashing/crypting your parameters*